# createComponent with generic types in lit-labs/react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, lit

I have [a web component](https://github.com/Trendyol/baklava/blob/next/src/components/select/bl-select.ts) written with Lit that uses Generic types for its `value` attribute and custom events.

```
@customElement('bl-select')
export default class BlSelect<ValueType extends FormValue = string> extends FormControlMixin(LitElement) {
```

I couldn't manage to be able to pass this generic type from React.

My Current situation:

```
export const BlSelect = React.lazy<ReactWebComponent<BlSelectType, {
  onBlSelect: EventName<CustomEvent<ISelectOption<ValueType>[]>>
}>>(() =>
  customElements.whenDefined('bl-select').then(elem => ({
      default: createComponent<BlSelectType>(
        {
          react: React,
          tagName: 'bl-select',
          elementClass: elem,
          events: {"onBlSelect":"bl-select"}
        }
      )
    })
));
```

Of course, `ValueType` in code above doesn't mean anything. I need to get that type from the user of `BlSelect` react component.

Any ideas how to manage this?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and it took me more than a full working day to figure out a solution that seems to work so I can keep generics for a React component created using Lit `createComponent()` helper.

I figured that you need to export a function component with type params on the function to be able to keep any generics on exported component. At least I could not find a way to do it directly with `export const` for example.

So you can't directly export the result of the `createComponent()` call when you need generics but you can create a small function component wrapper (with generics) that creates an instance of the component created by `createComponent()` and casts it to the correct type based on the given type argument.

It feels like a bit of a hack but at least I was able to get it to work nicely for the end user. It's not pretty and there may be a simpler way (or hopefully will be) but here's how it can work.

Here's an example based on your code above. I left out `React.lazy()` part from this since it makes the code slightly simpler and it seems unnecessary in your case as you're not doing any actual loading or heavy lifting in it directly anyway. I will also show how it can work with `React.lazy()` after the first example.

```
import React from 'react';
import { EventName, ReactWebComponent, createComponent } from '@lit/react';
import { FormValue } from '@open-wc/form-control';

// Lets import the web component class with a different name
import { BlSelect as BlSelectElement } from './bl-select';

// Let's assume your `<bl-select>` component has a `value` property typed as
// `ValueType` and that your `bl-select` event is a custom event similar to
// this (can be declared elsewhere):
export class BlSelectEvent<T> extends CustomEvent<{ value: T }> {
  constructor(detail: { value: T }) {
    super('bl-select', { detail, bubbles: true, cancelable: true, composed: true });
  }
}

// This is the regular result of createComponent() except wrapped in an IIFE with
// generics, but since this is not enough and we need to do a bit more work on this,
// the name here is suffixed with "Raw" for now.
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type
const BlSelectRaw = (function <ValueType extends FormValue = string>() {
  return createComponent({
    tagName: 'bl-select',
    elementClass: BlSelectElement<ValueType>,
    react: React,
    events: {
      onBlSelect: 'bl-select' as EventName<BlSelectEvent<ValueType> & { target: BlSelectElement<ValueType> }>,
    },
  });
})();

// This is a manual duplication of the inferred type of BlSelectRaw but with a
// persisting generic type argument. You can hover over `BlSelectRaw` above to
// see what you should have here.
type BlSelectGeneric<ValueType extends FormValue> = ReactWebComponent<
  BlSelectElement<ValueType>,
  {
    onBlSelect: EventName<BlSelectEvent<ValueType> & { target: BlSelectElement<ValueType> }>,
  }
>;
// Helper for typing the props of BlSelect
type SourceProps<ValueType extends FormValue> = React.ComponentProps<BlSelectGeneric<ValueType>>;

// A functional component with generics that wraps BlSelectRaw
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any, @typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type
export function BlSelect<ValueType extends FormValue = string>(props: SourceProps<ValueType>) {
  return React.createElement(BlSelectRaw as BlSelectGeneric<ValueType>, props);
}
```

With these definitions the `BlSelect` component can be used in JSX like so:

```
{/* TS will automatically infer that ValueType is string */}
<BlSelect
  value={'foo'}
  onBlSelect={(e): void => { console.log('bl-select', e.target, e.detail) }}
/>

{/* You can also declare the generic type manually */}
<BlSelect<string>
  value={'foo'}
  ...
/>
```

If you want to use `React.lazy()` anyway you can do so in `BlSelectRaw` like this:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any, @typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type
export const BlSelectRaw = React.lazy(<ValueType extends FormValue = string>() =>
  customElements.whenDefined('bl-select').then(() => ({
    default: createComponent({
      tagName: 'bl-select',
      elementClass: BlSelectElement<ValueType>,
      react: React,
      events: {
        onBlSelect: 'bl-select' as EventName<BlSelectEvent<ValueType> & { target: BlSelectElement<ValueType> }>,
      },
    })
  }))
);
```

Comment: I noticed that TypeScript seems to be quite slow to figure out the type information for usage of this component though (for me in VS Code). Not sure if it's because of this code above or some other reason it was slow for me today. At least I was sometimes seeing "Loading" for several seconds after hovering over the props after updating usage in JSX when testing this solution.